# Find two numbers in a binary search tree that add up to a third number

Tags: algorithm, big-o

You are given a BST of numbers. You have to find two numbers (a, b) in it such that `a + b = S`, in O(n) time and O(1) space.

What could be the algorithm?

One possible way could be two convert the BST to a doubly linked List and then start from the front and end:

```
if front + end > S then end--
```

Or:

```
if front + end < S then front++
```

Comment: Is this homework? (It's usually good to mention.)

Comment: are all the numbers positive?  can we assume that a valid pair of numbers exists?  if S is 8 and 4 is in the tree, can we give 4 as an answer?

Comment: @SR No this is not homework. Just curious.

Comment: @ Peter : Assume positive numbers and assume a solution exists. More than one solution can also exist.

Comment: Converting to a doubly linked list (or any other data structure for that matter) is *not* O(1) space.

Comment: @pax - that isn't the best solution. Just one of the possible solutions.

Comment: It's not a solution if one of the requirements is O(1) space. In fact, even a recursive solution will not do better than O(log n) space. Are those fixed requirements or just a wish list?

Comment: @PAX - The requirements are fixed. Outside these requirements there are ways to achieve this, both of us know.

Comment: Do you have pointers to the parents too? If yes then the recursive idea is good, you just need a little trick to transform it to a non-recursive one where you store only the 2 actual nodes, not the whole path to them because that can reconstructed with those parent pointers.

Comment: @yp - well the answer is NO. But it would be good to know how you think you will need a storage of only two nodes given the parent pointer.

Comment: Recursive means O(log n) space for the stack.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As others mentioned, you can't solve this in constant O(1) space. Furthermore, all the other solutions currently suggested use at least O(log^2 n) space, not O(log n) space: the stack has O(log n) frames and each frame has a O(log n) sized pointer.

Now, the currently accepted solution by @dharm0us destroys the BST by converting it into an array. This is unnecessary. Instead, use two iterators, one doing an in-order traversal and one doing a reverse-order traversal, and look for two numbers the same as you would in an array.  Each iterator has a stack with O(log n) frames with each frame holding a O(log n) size pointer for total space O(log^2 n). The time is clearly linear O(n).

Comment: "Each iterator has a stack with O(log n) frames with each frame holding a O(log n) size pointer for total space O(log^2 n)"??How !!

Comment: Tyson, could you explain the meaning of O(log n) size pointer. Thanks.

Comment: @user674669 You have n items in memory.  Each memory location has an address.  The iterator has to remember which element it is at by storing a memory address (this is called a pointer in programming languages like C).  The number of bits in this memory address must be Theta(log n) so that each item has a distinct memory address.

Comment: @TysonWilliams How ? your statement which I have Quoted , can you please elaborate.

Comment: @softy Is my response to user674669 not enough?

Answer (score 4):

I was asked this question in an interview recently.  When I was stuck, I was given a hint.

Hint: Let's say you need to solve this same problem for a sorted array, how would you solve it then.

Me: Keep two pointers. One at the beginning, another at the end. If the sum of elements at those pointers is less than the required sum, move the front pointer towards right, else move the back pointer towards left.

Interviewer: How could you do the same thing for a binary search tree?

Me: Do an in-order traversal, and save the pointers to nodes in an array. And use the same logic as in the case of arrays.

Interviewer: Yes, that works. But the space complexity is O(n). Could you reduce it?

Me (after a lot of time): Ok, convert the BST in a doubly linked list, using [this](http://cslibrary.stanford.edu/109/TreeListRecursion.html) algo. And then use the same logic as in the case of array. Space comlexity will be O(lg(n)) due to recursion.

Comment: Why do you have to covert the BST to an arry? Why can't you have to iterators, one doing an in-order traversal and one doing a reverse-order traversal, and look for two numbers that same as you would in an array?  Each iterator has a

Comment: reverse-order traversal?? You mean pre-order traversal?

Answer (score 3):

Try as I could, I'm not sure this is possible with a binary tree that has no parent pointers. `O(1)` space means you can neither use recursion (the stack growth is `O(log n)`) nor copying to a doubly linked list (`O(n)`).

The method you allude to *is* an `O(n)` time complexity solution but not with a normal binary tree. In fact, I answered a similar question in great detail [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1665395/link-list-algorithm-to-find-pairs-adding-up-to-10/1665411#1665411). That was solved with `O(n)` space but only because they weren't initially sorted.

It *is* possible with a tree containing parent pointers. If the child nodes have pointers to their parents, you can basically treat the tree as a doubly-linked list processed iteratively.

To do that, you run the start pointer down to the leftmost node and the end pointer down to the righmost node. You also maintain two variables to store the last movement (up or across, initially up) of each pointer so you can intelligently select the next move (the `front++` and `end--` in your question).

Then you can use the current pointers and last movements, along with the current sum, to decide which pointer to move (and how).

Comment: Well when I said convert to doubly linked List, I didn't mean to copy the tree to a doubly List. I actually meant converting it to a doubly List by making the left,rgight pointers play the role of NEXT, PREVIOUS.

Comment: You can't make it a doubly linked list with just next/previous, not unless you use recursion. And recursion is out because of the O(1) space requirement.

Comment: Made CW since I don't believe there's a solution within those requirements, unless parent pointers are allowed. I'll be happy if I'm proved wrong.

Comment: Made CW = ? Will post if I find the solution :(

Comment: @Geek: Community wiki. Since I'm not actually providing an answer to your question, I mark the answer CW (no rep either way). That's because, while it's my belief no solution exists, I'm not sure, and there's almost certainly people out there who know more than I.

Comment: I agree that the only way to get a solution involves one of the following relaxations:
1. Parent pointers
2. O(n log n) time
3. O(log n) space