# Numbers in Binary Search Tree(BST) adding to a certain value

Tags: algorithm, binary-tree

Given a BST, is it possible to find two numbers that add up to a given value, in O(n) time and little additional memory. By little additional memory, it is implied that you can't copy the entire BST into an array.

Comment: What property of a BST do you think makes it easier to solve the k-subset/subset-sum problem?

Comment: @LBushkin: Subset sum is irrelevant. We just need two numbers. An O(n^2) algorithm is trivial.

Comment: Is the BST balanced? Are we allowed to make changes to the tree and revert back?

Comment: @Moron: If it helps to solve, you can assume it's balanced. If it helps to modify the BST using limited amount of additional memory, yes that would be ok too.

Comment: @Moron O(n*log(n)) for BST is also trivial. Parse BST ( O(n) ) and check if the needed pair is present ( O(log(n) ).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Find two numbers in a binary search tree that add up to a third number](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1753843/find-two-numbers-in-a-binary-search-tree-that-add-up-to-a-third-number)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be accomplished in O(n) time and O(1) additional memory if you have both child and parent pointers. You keep two pointers, x and y, and start x at the minimum element and y at the maximum. If the sum of these two elements is too low, you move x to its successor, and if it's too high you move y to its predecessor. You can report a failure once x points to a larger element than y. Each edge in the tree is traversed at most twice for a total of O(n) edge traversals, and your only memory usage is the two pointers. Without parent pointers, you need to remember the sequence of ancestors to the root, which is at least Omega(log n) and possibly higher if the tree is unbalanced.

To find a successor, you can use the following pseudocode (analogous code for predecessor):

```
succ(x) {
  if (x.right != null) {
    ret = x.right;
    while (ret.left != null) ret = ret.left;
    return ret;
  } else {
    retc = x;
    while (retc.parent != null && retc.parent < x) retc = retc.parent;
    if (retc.parent != null && retc.parent > x) return retc.parent;
    else return null;
  }
}
```

Comment: This sounds more like it. Having references to parents would certainly help to achieve. Perhaps this would be the final acceptable answer, but I am waiting to see if someone can suggest one without needing parents and not requiring to store the ancestor tree.

Comment: @jonderry: Could you please edit your answer to add the code for the methods, GetSuccessor(x) and GetPredecessor(y)? Thanks.

Comment: @Gunner, isn't this almost exactly what I said (only moving in from the outside)? The main addition is pointing out the necessity of parent pointers, which I assumed because STL containers have them.

Comment: @Gunner, you need to keep parent pointers because otherwise you don't know how to get back up the tree when you've traversed to a deep level in the tree. You could avoid this by only remembering some parents, and traversing more edges, but you pay a large penalty in running time.

Comment: @jonderry: Thanks for the edit. I think it maybe possible to combine the two else ifs into a single block, since in either case you are comparing the value of x with one of it's ancestors.

Comment: `succ(x)` and the comparable `prev(x)` are amortized `O(ln(N))` if balanced; so the overall running time is actually `O(N ln(N))`.

Answer (score 2):

I think jonderry is very close, but the parent pointers require \Omega(n) memory, that is they add substantially to memory usage. What he is doing is two coordinated traversals in opposite directions (small to large and viveversa) trying to keep the sum always close to the target and you can manage that with two stacks, and the stacks can only grow up to the depth of the tree and that is O(log n). I don't know if that's "little" additional memory, but certainly it is less additional memory and o(n). So this is exactly as in jonderry own comment, but there is no runtime penalty because traversing a binary tree using only a stack is a well known and efficient and definitely O(n) operation. So you have increasing iterator ii and a decreasing iterator di.

```
x = ii.next()
y = di.next()
while (true) {
  try:
    if x + y > target {y = di.next()}
    if x + y < target {x = ii.next()}
    if x + y == target {return (x,y)}
  except IterError:
    break
}
return None
```

I had just run into the same problem in the context of computing the pseudomedian, the median of all pairwise averages in a sample.

Comment: So to implement ii.next() and di.next(),you would need to maintain stack right?

Comment: I guess there has to be a compromise between your and jonderry's method. If references to parents exist, we can always do the task with constant additional memory. Your method would be the best if no references to parent's exist. Also, the additional memory used is also minimal by your method.

Comment: Hey it just occurred to me, if you have to search up the stack, then why not search down the tree in the first place. That is the O(nlog(n)). If you need to keep on reaching to parent nodes, it would be same as going down from the root in the first place. This applies to jonderry's solution also.

Comment: Gunner-1 yep you don't need me to rewrite a tree traversal right?

Comment: Gunner-3 unclear, but it's a traversal, why are we still discussing it? There is nothing to discover about it.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, if you parse it as it would be a sorted array.

Comment: But that would mean you would need additional memory which is equal to the number of elements in the BST. The original post strictly wants to prevent this.

Comment: @Gunner have you ever heard such words as `inorder`, `preorder` or `postorer`?

Comment: Yes I am aware of the words, but would it be possible to perform two different parsing and combine the two conveniently to obtain the desired answer.